# How can I create a Trend Line in Amazon QuickSight?

Tags: calculation, trend, amazon-quicksight

I need to create a Trend calculation for a dashboard in Amazon QuickSight. Basically I need the same thing that the Trend function in Excel allows.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of February 2020 QuickSight does not provide an ability to create a trend line. Your best strategy at the moment is to calculate trend line values outside of QuickSight (in your ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) pipeline) and only use QuickSight to show the line.

We do know that customers need this ability so we are planning to provide this functionality in one of the upcoming releases.

Comment: Has this change in the past 3 years?